# ServiceStack DTO For Dropdown Lists

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I have a request object for a POST in a ServiceStack service that looks like this:

```
[Route("/jtip/cases/search", "POST")]
public class FindAgencyCases : IReturn<List<AgencyCaseResponse>>
{
    public int? AgencyId { get; set; }
    public string AgencyCaseNumber { get; set; }
    public int? ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string IndividualFirstName { get; set; }
    public string IndividualLastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
    public string LicenseState { get; set; }
    public string IndividualType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RequestStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RequestEndDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int? ResultsLimit { get; set; }
}
```

The values for AgencyId, ServiceId, etc need to come from dropdown lists. This DTO doesn't care how it gets those values, but I need to provide collections for my agencies, services, etc.

Because this is a request object, I can't grab my lists from the database and send them to the client. So how would I go about getting the lists for my dropdowns (in an HTML form) that contain the values to populate the above request DTO? I'm I overlooking something really obvious?

Comment: How are you serving up the HTML form in general? Is it an ASP.NET web form, MVC view, Razor view delivered via ServiceStack, plain static HTML file, etc.?

Comment: My consumer is ASP.Net MVC using the ServiceStack C# client. At this point I'm attempting to just create an empty request, which brings back a response containing an object with the collections for all of my dropdown lists, which will be called when the form is drawn.

Comment: What do you mean by "Because this is a request object, I can't grab my lists from the database and send them to the client"? What is the reason for not getting the response data from DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply create another request / route that lists the available agencies and services?

```
[Route("/jtip/cases/agencies", "GET")]
public class AgencyListRequest : IReturn<List<Agency>>
{
}

public class Agency {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("/jtip/cases/services", "GET")]
public class ServiceListRequest : IReturn<List<Service>>
{
}

public class Service {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. I have a request that brings back all of my collections when the form is presented.